# Unknown linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Okay so I'm just prepping for my linear algebra final and I've come across questions like this before and I'm not sure how to solve. It seems pretty simple and I have an idea of what's going on but I don't have a concrete algorithm in my head for solving these problems.

Let $T: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^3$ be a linear transformation such that $T(1,1) = (1,0,2) $ and $T(2,3)=(1,-1,4)$. Find $T(8,11)$.

My initial guess is that $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and that may have something to do with the solution, can someone send me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's important that these vectors span $\Bbb R^2$. In particular, find constants $a$ and $b$ such that

$$a(1, 1) + b(2, 3) = (8, 11)$$

Then apply linearity of $T$ to find

$$T(8, 11) = T(a(1, 1) + b(2,3))$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the fact that the image of the two vectors defines the matrix associated to the linear transformation in that basis; specifically, the images of $(2,3)$ and $(1,1)$ , seen as column vectors are the $3\times 2$- matrix of the transformation. You can then multiply the matrix by the vector $(8,11)$ to get the image of $(8,11)$ under $T$.